# How to enumerate all open documents (including previewHTML) in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

In order to see which of my text document providers actually have an open document (and hence need an update on certain events) I want to enumerate all open documents in vscode. `workspace.textDocuments` however returns only standard documents, not those created with previewHTML. How can I get those to compare URIs to my provider's URIs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a limitation as of VS Code 1.20. See these issues for more information:

- https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/20075
- https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/15178

Comment: Aside: we're investigating improving the html preview API and would love to have your feedback on the proposal: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/pull/41853